# Grails iterate over objects in the controller

Tags: grails, loops, controllers

In Grails, to display a list of something in a table, i normally do the following:

My controller is

```
thingController {

def temp2 = something.findAllByXXX(yyy)

[temp : temp2]
}
```

And in my view i have:

```
<g:each var="it" in="${temp}">
${it.someThing}
${it.someThingSomething}
<g:each>
```

I don't know if this is the best approach. Is it possible to do this exact same thing, but instead of calling all the objects, and then in the gsp iterate over them, do this all controller-side. Meaning, instead of passing all the objects to the view, pass single objects.

Comment: That doesn't seem possible, as the controller cannot call `render()` more than once per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if this is the best approach. Is it possible to do this exact same thing, but instead of calling all the objects, and then in the gsp iterate over them, do this all controller-side. Meaning, instead of passing all the objects to the view, pass single objects

I don't think I understand what your proposing as an alternative to your code above. But AFAIK the code above is the most common way to display a list of items in a GSP, so unless it's causing you a specific problem, I wouldn't bother looking for alternatives.

Comment: Ok, very much appreciated. Sometimes i have doubts about the best approach to follow to do certain things, and altought it work, there could be simpler and better ways to do it, and i'm always learning :p If there is not better way, i'll accept the answer :p

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I don't think it's a good idea unless it's for a very specific reason.  For example, if you always expect two objects from your query, and they need to be display differently, then you might want to have a model like `[object1: temp2[0], object2: temp2[1]]`.

A good way to structure views to avoid the clutter of iteration is with templates.  You can have a view like this:

```
<g:each var="it" in="${temp}">
  <g:render template="someThing" model="[someThingInstance: it]"/>
</g:each>
```

And a template `_someThing.gsp` that displays a single object:

```
<div>${someThingInstance.field1}</div>
<div>${someThingInstance.field2}</div>
```